# Retrieve the item from the list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the list of `Courses` from the `courseData` list item.

However, the following returns me `boolean`.

```
var course = courseData.Courses.Select(x => x.Entities.Select(a => a.courseId == courseDto.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I assume one of those `Select`s should be a `Where`.

Comment: `var course = courseData.Courses.SelectMany(x => x.Entities.Where(a => a.courseId == courseDto.Id));` would be my guess. Why you're calling it course I have no idea.

Comment: If you want a list why are you using `FirstOrDefault`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `course` is of type `IEnumerable<bool>` because in your *inner* `Select` clause you're projecting from some type `a` and returning `a.courseId == courseDto.Id` (`bool`) which results in an `IEnumerable<bool>` after the provided lambda is executed for each element of `x.Entities`.

Once the execution of the *outer* `Select` clause is performed this then results in having a type `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool>>` which when you then call `FirstOrDefault()` upon; simply results in retrieving the first `IEnumerable<bool>` element.

Now, you're most likely looking for the `Where` clause so that you can retain all the elements that pass the predicate `a => a.courseId == courseDto.Id`. We will then flatten the `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Entity>>` into `IEnumerable<Entity>` and then collect to a list or retrieve the first element if exists else the default for reference types (`null`).

To retrieve a list of courses.

```
var course = 
      courseData.Courses
                .SelectMany(x => x.Entities.Where(a => a.courseId == courseDto.Id))
                .ToList();
```

To retrieve the first item from the list of courses.

```
var course = 
     courseData.Courses
               .SelectMany(x => x.Entities.Where(a => a.courseId == courseDto.Id))
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Result = Course_Object.Where(u => u.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```